# Flexible grid row heights in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am having some issues with grid areas and content overflowing out of the area defined.

In my code below, you can see the blue content area has enough content that should push the green footer downwards, yet it doesn't.

I assume it's something to do with the `grid-template-rows` property, but I have no idea how to fix it. Is it even possible?

I love the inherent flexibility of grid, but this one issue has me stumped and seems to put a downer on everything, meaning I cannot have content that's bigger then a couple of paragraphs!

I have the following: [codepen.io example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeeRbr)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

a {
  color: #191970;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  /*background: linear-gradient(white, #e0f7ff);*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo nav" "logo content" "aside content" "footer footer";
  grid-gap: 10px;
  font-family: 'Copse';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}


/*@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:  "logo"
        "nav"
        "content"
        "footer";
  grid-gap: 10px;
 }
}*/

header {
  background-color: red;
  grid-area: logo;
}

header img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: nav;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

section {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: content;
}

aside {
  background-color: grey;
  grid-area: aside;
}

footer {
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Copse" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg/1024px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg.png" />
  </header>

  <nav>
    <h2>systems</h2>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h2>terminal</h2>
      <h3>logged 16-08-2017</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget sapien dolor. Sed cursus nunc et erat efficitur, vel tempor purus sollicitudin. Etiam interdum volutpat felis ac pretium. In at mi sit amet arcu elementum luctus sit amet nec nibh. Integer
        suscipit mauris libero, in pulvinar metus volutpat ut. Etiam fermentum nunc a fringilla lobortis. Integer aliquam ut sapien vel ullamcorper.
      </p>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>terminal</h2>
      <h3>logged 15-08-2017</h3>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
      <p>
        Fusce vulputate ligula felis, in laoreet eros hendrerit vel. Fusce urna velit, malesuada a scelerisque quis, mollis sed tortor. Morbi lobortis, ante sit amet placerat feugiat, nulla tortor pulvinar velit, a venenatis sem dui ac turpis. Quisque semper
        quam euismod ipsum iaculis ullamcorper. Praesent quis lectus turpis. In a ipsum eleifend, pretium arcu vel, placerat arcu. Fusce vehicula tristique tempus. Mauris gravida orci sed nulla posuere euismod. Aenean posuere blandit cursus.
      </p>
    </article>

    <div>
      « Previous Page — Next Page »
    </div>
  </section>

  <aside>
    <h2>sub-systems</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>

  <footer>
    <a href="#">privacy policy</a>
    <a href="#">terms &amp; conditions</a> copyright &copy; 2017
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems to only happen when you span multiple rows. If your content is just in one row it will push it down without any problems. I'm not sure how to solve this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `height` of the container limited to `100vh`.

If you want the container to expand with content, then instead use `min-height: 100vh`.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvvZNL